# Reject a promise within an http.get catch block

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, promise, catch-block

I have this asynchronous function which uses http.get inside a promise.

```
private _getSchema(fileName): any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(fileName)
            .map(this._extractData)
            .catch(this._handleError)
            .subscribe(schema => resolve(schema));
    });
};
```

Rather than call this._handleError in the catch block, I would like to reject my promise and pass reject the error object. How do I do that?

attempt:

```
private _getSchema(fileName): any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(fileName)
            .map(this._extractData)
            .catch(err => reject(err))
            .subscribe(schema => resolve(schema));
    });
};
```

gives error:

> Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type '(err: any, caught: Observable) => ObservableInput<{}>'. 
>   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

I'm using typescript

Comment: does just `.catch(reject)` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises fit better as http results than observables, so I suggest you to go the promise way:

```
private _getSchema(fileName): any {
    return this.http.get(fileName).toPromise().then(x => this._extractData(x));
};
```

The way you tried does not work because [`Observable.prototype.catch`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catchproto.md) has a different signature (It needs to provide a new observable to continue with). Subscribing to onError is what you were searching for:

```
private _getSchema(fileName): any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(fileName)
            .map(this._extractData)
            .subscribe(resolve, reject);
    });
};
```

But this is exactly what `observable.toPromise()` does.

Comment: That's elegant. How do I add error handling?  `.then(x => {this._extractData(x)},  err => {/*handle error*/});` ?

Comment: That's a way. Or `.then(x=>this._extractData(x)).catch(err => this._handleError(err))`. But why would you add error handling here, you just asked us how to remove it?

Comment: I didn't ask to remove it. I asked how I can add it in (using the reject, the promise will return the error to later handle. So your bottom block of code in your answer would be best for that?

Comment: Yeah, in most cases a .catch at the end is the way to go. If you want the resulting promise to still be rejected, use: `.catch(e => { this.handle(e); throw e; })`